# Why does sprintf('%i', x) show scientific notation?

Tags: string, matlab, printf

Try this in Matlab R2015b:

```
>> sprintf('%i\n',uint64(2)^62)
ans =
4611686018427387904 %// correct

>> sprintf('%i\n',uint64(2)^63)
ans =
9.223372e+18 %// why scientific notation?
```

In R2010b it's worse: a number as low as `uint64(2)^31` already causes this behaviour:

```
>> sprintf('%i\n',uint64(2)^31)
ans =
2.147484e+009
```

**Why does `sprintf` use scientific notation with the `'%i'` or `'%d'` format specifiers? Can this be avoided?**

Using `num2str` instead of `sprintf` is not a solution for me. Even though it does avoid scientific notation,

```
>> num2str(uint64(2)^63)
ans =
9223372036854775808 %// correct
```

I need to use `sprintf` because `num2str` doesn't support the "leading spaces" format specifier:

```
>> sprintf('% 25i\n',uint64(2)^62, uint64(2)^50)
ans =
      4611686018427387904
         1125899906842624 %// correct: leading spaces to give 25 characters for each number

>> num2str([uint64(2)^62;uint64(2)^50], '% 25i\n')
ans =
4611686018427387904
   1125899906842624 %// incorrect: no leading spaces

>> num2str(uint64(2)^50, '% 25i\n')
ans =
1125899906842624 %// incorrect: no leading spaces
```

Comment: Is this because the maximum integer size (2^63-1 afaik) is exceeded?

Comment: @Adriaan No, that can't be the cause, because the maximum is actually [2^64-1](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint64.html)

Comment: Sounds like a bug IMHO.

Comment: @rayryeng See also the result of `num2str(rand(1,3) * 9999, '% 25.5e\n')`: space left-padding except for the first. Weird too

Comment: @LuisMendo :S? What is with the inconsistency of the printing?

Comment: Have you tried `%u` for unsigned integer?

Comment: @beaker Hey! That's seems to be it! Make that an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607597/matlab-sprintf-formatting), it seems that MATLAB, for some reason (possibly because it's expecting a signed integer from `%i` but you're giving it an unsigned one), treats the very-big-number (2^63) as a `float`, and converts it to scientific notation which is also why if you write `sprintf('%.18i\n',bitshift(uint64(2),62))` you end up losing precision:

```
9.223372036854775800e+18 vs. 9223372036854775808
```

Using `%u` as opposed to `%i` seems to produce the correct result:

```
sprintf('%u\n',bitshift(uint64(2),62))

ans =

9223372036854775808
```

(It makes more sense to use `bitshift` in this specific scenario)

Comment: Not just very big – specifically the critical value is `intmax('int64')` (`2^63-1`). Always use the appropriate format specifier.